# how do I create a matrix of sums from a list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, tuples

I have a list of tuples [(1,1),(1,7),(4,0),(3,0).......(x,y)]

How do I create a table that has as the column headers the values 0->max x_value, rows as 0-> max y_value and cells as the count of the number of items with that exact value?

example input:[(0,1),(1,1),(1,0),(0,0),(0,1)]

example output:
[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuLW2.png)

Comment: What have you attempted to do this?

Answer (score 0):

generating some random samples:

```
import numpy as np
sample = [(np.random.randint(4), np.random.randint(4)) for _ in range(10)]
```

the samples:

```
[(2, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 3), (3, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 2), (3, 0), (0, 0)]
```

the code:

```
np_mat = np.array(sample)
res_mat = np.zeros(shape=tuple(np_mat.max(axis=0) + 1))
for el in np_mat:
    res_mat[el[1], el[0]] += 1
```

the output:

```
[[3. 0. 0. 2.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0.]]
```